# UINavigationController UIViewController stack Delegate

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a parent UIViewController that  present a UINavigationController->UIViewController  in modal form style, the problem is that the first UIViewController on the stack is the one that has the delegate reference to the parent UIViewController and after programmatically pushing several UIViewControllers and dismissing the from the last UIViewController on the stack I ended with no way to call the delegate back to the parent ViewController.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not add a member that points to the delegate in the root controller? Just make sure its a week reference to avoid a retain cycle.

Comment: Thanks very much, could you please provide some example code?

Comment: Thanks Freddy for you comment I was very helpful here is what worked for me,

// Instantiated the first UIViewController
StepsBeginViewController *firstVC = [[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];

// using the reference to the first UIViewController delegate passing self 
[firstVC.delegate StepsBeginViewControllerDidFinish:self]; 

//On parent UIViewController

- (void)StepsBeginViewControllerDidFinish:(StepsBeginViewController *)controller{
    
    NSLog(@"Message is: %@", controller.jobData);
}


Message is: (
    "Pump Delivery",
        (
        "Pump Delivery...